# Keep Mouse Cursor Visible while typing in windows text box

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a small windows form, not WPF, that is a quick reference tool, where the user types a value and presses a button, and a query opens a details view with data.

When the user types in the text box, I want the mouse cursor to always remain visible, to make it easier to click the query button any time, without having to move the mouse to make the mouse cursor re-appear. Other software does this, like Visual Studio’s text editor window. The mouse cursor is always visible.

I would like to use the native Windows  “SystemParametersInfo” function with the SPI_SETMOUSEVANISH flag set to not hide the mouse when the user types, and then return it to the default setting when my form closes. 
Has anyone successfully used the Windows SystemParametersInfo function for showing the mouse cursor?  I can’t seem to get it to work. 
If anyone could advise me how to either trap the event that hides the mouse cursor, or properly apply SystemParameters info, I would really appreciate this.

Here is the code I am using.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SystemParametersInfo",   SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(SPI uiAction, uint uiParam, ref bool pvParam, SPIF fWinIni);

    [Flags]
    public enum SPIF
    {
    None = 0x00,
    /// <summary>Writes the new system-wide parameter setting to the user profile.</summary>
    SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01,
    /// <summary>Broadcasts the WM_SETTINGCHANGE message after updating the user profile.</summary>
    SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 0x02,
    /// <summary>Same as SPIF_SENDCHANGE.</summary>
    SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.Description("SPI_(System-wide parameter - Used in SystemParametersInfo function )")]
    public enum SPI : uint
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the two mouse threshold values and the mouse speed.
    /// </summary>
    SPI_GETMOUSE = 0x0003,

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the two mouse threshold values and the mouse speed.
    /// </summary>
    SPI_SETMOUSE = 0x0004,

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the state of the Mouse Vanish feature. The pvParam 
    parameter must point to a BOOL
    /// variable that receives 'true' if enabled or 'false' otherwise.
    /// Windows 2000/NT, Windows 98/95:  This value is not supported.
    /// </summary>
    SPI_GETMOUSEVANISH = 0x1020,

    /// <summary>
    /// Turns the Vanish feature on or off. This feature hides the mouse pointer when the user types; the pointer reappears 
    /// when the user moves the mouse. The pvParam parameter specifies true for on and false for off. The default is off (false).
    /// In Windows 2000/NT, Windows 98/95, this value is not supported.
    /// </summary>
    SPI_SETMOUSEVANISH = 0x1021
    }

       private void disableMouseVanish()
    {
        // Query current system parameter for
        // whether or not the mouse is hidden
        // while typing in a textbox.
        //
        successfullyQueried = NativeMethods.SystemParametersInfo(
            NativeMethods.SPI.SPI_GETMOUSEVANISH, 0, ref mouseHiddenWhileTyping, NativeMethods.SPIF.None);
        //
        if (successfullyQueried && mouseHiddenWhileTyping)
        {
            // Set flag to false and apply.
            mouseHiddenWhileTyping = false;
            //
            // Set system parameter to always show mouse
            // cursor while typing in textboxes.
            successfullyQueried = NativeMethods.SystemParametersInfo(
                NativeMethods.SPI.SPI_SETMOUSEVANISH, 0, ref mouseHiddenWhileTyping,
                NativeMethods.SPIF.SPIF_SENDCHANGE | NativeMethods.SPIF.SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
            //
            // Verify was successfully set.
            if (successfullyQueried && !mouseHiddenWhileTyping)
            {
                // I get here every time, but the mouse cursor
                // still gets hidden while I type.

                // Set flag to ignore showing mouse after
                // every key press event.
                //skipShowMouse = true;                    
                MessageBox.Show("Non-zero return (true) indicates sucess.");
            }
            else if (!successfullyQueried)
            {
                ///
                /// We could read the value, but
                /// not set it.

                MessageBox.Show("Error: Failed to set the specified system parameter.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes it does. I am referring to the mouse cursor, and not the textbox caret. Make a form with a textbox and a button. While you are typing, you cannot see the mouse cursor. Open notepad, and while you are typing, try to find the mouse cursor. To make it re-appear, you need to move the mouse.

Comment: TAW, Have you actually opened notepad and started typing, to verify my claim that the windows mouse caret is hidden while you are typing?

Comment: The mouse always disappears. You have to move the physical mouse, and then it reappears. This is normally OK, but for the form I am using, I want to duplicate the way the visual studio editor works, where there are always 2 carets visible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54580/discussion-between-matt-fomich-and-taw).

Comment: Am I to understand that you have the "hide pointer while typing" Windows setting set, and you want to introduce the bug some programs such as Visual Studio have where they ignore that setting? Or are you seeing this behaviour even with that setting unset?

Comment: John, I have a form where I always want the mouse cursor to be visible, even when the user is typing in a specific textbox. The only software I know of that also does this is the visual studio editor window. I only mentioned this as an example of what I am trying to do. Right now on every key_up event from the textbox, I call the SendMessage API, and I sent WM_SetCursor and this works, but the cursor turns off for every key down event and then back on with key_up. I could not get sub-classing to work, so only other method is to override Windows setting and return it when done.

Comment: A comment at http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/334728/mouse-cursor-not-hidden-when-typing suggests that their problem could relate to their not using the `EDIT` class in the underlying `CreateWindow` call. Maybe you could replicate that, though you'd have to duplicate the core editing functionality.

Comment: OpenOffice has the same problem, and again, not basing on EDIT seems to be part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this I have to admit that I was wrong and indeed the usual behaviour of an edit control seems to to hide the mouse cursor **when the user starts typing**.

There seems to be a way to use `SystemParametersInfo` like you try, but somehow after reading about it I was not sure if that would change a system-wide setting or not.

Of course you would set and reset it on `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` and once you have a working version **please do post it here!**

But I found a workaround [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/448936/cursor-disappears-while-typing-in-text-box), one could call it a hack I guess but with a little friendly tweaking it seems to work.

Here is what I did: Create a **dummy ListView** to `Capture` and release the mouse when appropriate!

```
ListView dummy;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dummyLV = new ListView();
    dummyLV.Visible = false;
    dummyLV.Enabled = false;
    this.Controls.Add(dummyLV );
    //..
```

I set Capture to true in these textbox events:

- `MouseEnter`
- `KeyDown`

`dummyLV.Capture = true;`

And I reset it to false here:

- `MouseLeave`
- `MouseMove`
- `KeyUp` (might not be necessary)

`dummyLV.Capture = false;`

Obviously a hack but I couldn't find fault in it so far..The mouse stays visible and can be used for selecting text in any way..

**Note**: Instead of **ListView** many other controls like even a simple **Label** will work as well, as Matt points out in his last comment..

Comment: It's the usual behaviour, if the user has their system set to do so. It's not the usual behaviour, if they do not.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the pointer. But it is on to hide by default, right. I don't think changing a system wide setting for a certain spot can be called 'introducing a bug'. Especially if the customers wants it.  But to be on the safe side I would probably add a program option for it.

Comment: If the end user wants it for this application alone, then yes, it's not a bug, though it's strange that they would want it here and not everywhere else. If the person speccing it is not the end-user, then it's probably a bug in the spec; doing the opposite to what the user asks is generally not correct. Certainly that Visual Studio doesn't hide the cursor is considered a known issue, though currently marked "Won't Fix" with the explanation that it isn't high enough priority.

Comment: Hm, yes and no. I think it is really about usability and here it makes a difference if you are in a small textbox, where 2 cursors are a crowd or in a big edit pane that spans the screen and where there is really no reason to hide the cursor. The system setting was probably introduced when most screens were tiny VGA things where you could spot the reappearing mouse easily from the first movement. This is different on a 28"+ screen, where it sometimes gets lost.. Well just my 5cents.

Comment: No, this is about usability and if the user says "hide the cursor", they probably want the cursor hidden and if they say "don't hide the cursor" they don't probably want the cursor hidden. There are certainly times when you should do things differently to how the user has set their system up, but it's something to be **very** careful about for limited cases (what makes this application a special case? is the question to answer). The only thing cited here so far is bugs 334728 & 537390, not any reason to replicate those bugs. The OP **might** have a sound reason, but they haven't given it.

Comment: Well, let's agree to disagree. I think that a) 99%+ of all users have no idea about the setting and b) if asked they would be hard put to decide and would, to quote Mr Reagan say: "It depends". Which is not an option. I am glad VS keeps the cursor visible. As does Firefox while I am typing this, but where I don't really like it.

Comment: So am I personally, but then for that reason I only have it set to "hide pointer" when I'm checking I don't have this bug myself :)

Comment: TaW, Thanks for posting a suggested fix, but I need the functionality of a textbox. I maintain software for a group where I work, and this is part of my software. This functionality was my idea for one particular form, as part of a larger upgrade, and no one has seen this form yet, so no big deal. This was my attempt to make it as easy as possible for the end user.

Comment: Hey Taw, I just actually read your post, and tried it and it works! This is a very ugly hack, though.  I will implement this and try to get systemparameters api working later.  Thanks, Matt

Comment: Hey this hack works quite well. Instead of a listview, I used a hidden label, which is a more lightweight control. If anyone needs this hack, any windows control that can receive mouse capture would probably work.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that right after a key is pushed the Current Cursor is being set to null.

However, it isn't being disposed of, and instead is being stored elsewhere.

My fix is the following:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

Cursor storedCursor = null;

private void TextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)        
{
    storedCursor = Cursor.Current;
}

private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Cursor.Current == null)
    {
        Cursor.Current = storedCursor;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can set the Current Cursor to anything.

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
Cursor.Current = Cursors.IBeam;
```